# How to increase Heap size of JVM

Tags: java

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at SQLite.Vm.step(Native Method)
        at SQLite.Database.get_table(Database.java:314)
        at SQLite.JDBC2z.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(JDBCStatement.java:120)
        at SQLite.JDBC2z.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(JDBCStatement.java:168)
        at TestData.readData(TestData.java:21)
        at TestData.main(TestData.java:41)
```

Answer (score 93):

Following are few options available to change Heap Size.

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack size
```

```
java -Xmx256m TestData.java
```

Answer (score 15):

Java command line parameters

```
-Xms: initial heap size
-Xmx: Maximum heap size
```

if you are using Tomcat. Update `CATALINA_OPTS` environment variable

```
export CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms16m -Xmx256m;
```

Answer (score 13):

Start the program with -Xms=[size] -Xmx -XX:MaxPermSize=[size] -XX:MaxNewSize=[size]

For example -

```
-Xms512m -Xmx1152m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m
```

Answer (score 9):

By using the `-Xmx` command line parameter when you invoke java.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Answer (score 8):

Use -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m to control your heap size (1024m is only for demonstration, the exact number depends your system memory). Setting minimum and maximum heap size to the same is usually a best practice since JVM doesn't have to increase heap size at runtime.

Comment: exact means  -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m or actual physical memory?

Answer (score 2):

-XmxSIZE

For example:
-Xmx1024M