# Increase JVM max heap size for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jvm, heap-memory

I am trying to increase the max heap size for my Eclipse. I have tried specifying in `eclipse.ini` or through the command line, but are not working.

My max heap size has the exact same limit before (running jconsole) and after (`System.out.println(java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());`) starting Eclipse. 1.8G

1. Is there any way to modify JVM heap size before it is launched (ex. a config file?)
2. What could I be doing wrong when specifying heap size to Eclipse?

This is the command:

```
./eclipse/eclipse -debug -consoleLog -vmargs -Xms1000m -Xmx6000m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimitcl
```

This is my `eclipse.ini` (which values are overwritten by the specified eclipse launching parameters):

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=6000m
-Xms1000m
-Xmx6000m
```

Answer (score 28):

It is possible to increase heap size allocated by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) by using command line options.

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack size
```

If you are using the tomcat server, you can change the heap size by going to Eclipse/Run/Run Configuration and select Apache Tomcat/your_server_name/Arguments and under VM arguments section use the following:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m -Xmx512M
```

If you are not using any server, you can type the following on the command line before you run your code:

```
java -Xms64m -Xmx256m HelloWorld
```

More information on increasing the heap size can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452765/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-jvm)

Comment: This is the only thing that has worked for me so far, that is, specify at every runtime in eclipse the Xmx etc. arguments. I am running my own hadoop, mahout etc. programs in my laptop in pseudo distributed mode.

Comment: I know it's two years old, but it's baffling that this answer has so many upvotes. It does nothing to answer the question, which is specifically about Eclipse, and which already shows an understanding of setting the heap size from the command line. And what does Tomcat have to do with anything?

Comment: @MartinMcCallion It has so many upvotes because when when people google thing like "increase jvm ECLIPSE" this is one of the topics that comes up....and for everyday developers that use tomcat with eclipse this is helpful information.

Comment: is there any other way to edit heap size in eclipse (From properties)

Answer (score 14):

You can use this configuration:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Comment: It actually helped and improved my startup time as well !

Comment: eclipse starting,  app run / debug is now faster. thank you.

Comment: @Vrajesh where do i place this code ? eclipse > configuration > config.ini

Comment: is there any other way to edit heap size in eclipse (From properties)

Comment: @JustCode007 Which version are you using? i useded Eclipse Luna  Path:-> c:\program files\eclipse\eclipse.ini  its based on eclipse version for .ini file

Answer (score 4):

Try to modify the `eclipse.ini` so that both `Xms` and `Xmx` are of the same value:

```
-Xms6000m
-Xmx6000m
```

This should force the Eclipse's VM to allocate `6GB` of heap right from the beginning.

But be careful about either using the `eclipse.ini` or the command-line `./eclipse/eclipse -vmargs ...`. It should work in both cases but pick one and try to stick with it.

Comment: I tried running just ./eclipse/eclipse -debug -consoleLog, and modified the eclipse.ini. Not working. I have to say I am user inigo but I run this command as sudo. If I do it as inigo I get problems with dependencies.

Comment: How do you check for the heap size. Could you use `jstat -gccapacity`?  you can also enable logging `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=jvm.log` to see which parameters are in the end passed into the VM.

Answer (score 2):

`--launcher.XXMaxPermSize`

`256m`

Try to bump that value up!