# How to increase application heap size in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jvm, heap-memory

Some say I need to do that in Run Configurations for my application. When I open that window, could you please tell me how to set the right argument and the amount of memory? Say how to set 2GB or 1.5GB?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382932/increase-jvm-max-heap-size-eclipse

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In the run configuration you want to customize (just click on it) open the tab `Arguments` and add `-Xmx2048m`in the VM arguments section.
You might want to set the `-Xms` as well (small heap size).

Comment: it didnt work. its still taking the old value -Xmx512M

Answer (score 34):

1. Go to Eclipse Folder
2. Find Eclipse Icon in Eclipse Folder
3. Right Click on it you will get option "Show Package Content"
4. Contents folder will open on screen
5. If you are on Mac then you'll find "MacOS"
6. Open MacOS folder you'll find eclipse.ini file
7. Open it in word or any file editor for edit

   ...

   ```
    -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

    -Xms40m

    -Xmx512m
   ```

   ...
8. Replace -Xms512m to -Xmx1024m
9. Save the file and restart your Eclipse
10. Have a Nice time :)

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean 512 to 1024 ?

Comment: This will increase the heap size for all of Eclipse, not just the target application.

Answer (score 17):

Find the Run button present on the top of the Eclipse,
then select Run Configuration ->
Arguments, in VM arguments section just mention the heap size you want to extend as below:

```
-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse Folder there is eclipse.ini file.  Increase size  `-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m`

Answer (score 1):

Open `eclipse.ini`

Search for `-Xmx512m` or maybe more size it is.

Just change it to a required size such as I changed it to `-Xmx1024m`