# Java memory heap error

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, heap-memory, helios

[image: Error message screenshot]

I didn't find anything for this error on the net, can anyone help? I have a stub class that is more than 30,000 lines of code, maybe it caused the problem?

Comment: Don't open Quick Diff on a stub class, why would you want to do that, anyway?

Comment: Is the error message from the Java Virtual Machine. Or from the operating system? If the later, your options are very limited.

Comment: In case you are not able to find through code... then use [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313393/how-to-increase-heap-size-in-eclipse

Comment: read this http://insidecoding.com/2011/09/15/how-to-increase-tomcat-heap-size-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 2):

> i have a stub class that is more than 30 000 line code maybe it caused the problem ??

Yes, this could certainly be the root cause. In any case, it seems that Eclipse is running out of heap space. Try assigning more heap space to Eclipse. In your `eclipse.ini`, change

```
-Xmx512m
```

to a higher value, like

```
-Xmx1024m
```

See also http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Eclipse FAQ at http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Answer (score 0):

By the way you can increase size of java heap space based on your application need and I always recommend this to avoid using default JVM heap values. if your application is large and lots of object created you can change size of heap space by using JVM options -Xms and -Xmx.  Xms denotes starting size of Heap while -Xmx denotes maximum size of Heap in Java. There is another parameter called -Xmn which denotes Size of new generation of Java Heap Space. Only thing is you can not change the size of Heap in Java dynamically, you can only provide Java Heap Size parameter while starting JVM.

Comment: the problem is solved thanks! I increased the heap size in the "eclipse.ini" to 1024 but the problem persists so i increased it again the 2048 and it worked!