# Eclipse Exception with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi I am partially testing an application and It has a problem with heap space.
Here is sample code

```
public class Test {


Test()
{
    byte[] b = new byte[744678306];
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Test t=new Test();
}

}
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Here is eclipse ini configuration

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms800m
-Xmx999m
```

Working env : ubuntu 12 on vBox.

Thanks advance.

Comment: You're welcome in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking for space for about 750MB, but your program starts with a maximum allowed of 256,

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313393/how-to-increase-heap-size-in-eclipse)

Just add -Xmx2048M (for 2048 MB, you can change that number) in the list of VM arguments in the corresponding run configuration.

Comment: so should I change -XX:MaxPermSize=800m ?

Comment: No. Eclipse memory configuration has nothing to do with executed program heap.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't pasted the link correctly. Take a look at it now, there you will find an explanation on how to increase the heap size permitted.

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipse startup configuration which you have pasted has nothing to do with your problem. Eclipse does not execute your code in its own JVM; it starts a separate JVM with the arguments you explicitly specify *within Eclipse*.

After you run the application once, a Run Configuration entry will be created for it. Go to that entry (Run -> Configurations...) and, under VM arguments, specify more memory with `-Xmx`. By default, Java 7 sets `mx` to 1 GB or a quarter of the total RAM, whichever is less.

Answer (score 1):

For avoiding the out of memory error do the following steps. <kbd>Eclipse</kbd> -> <kbd>run</kbd> -> <kbd>run configuration</kbd> -> <kbd>arguments</kbd>. Then in VM arguments type as below.

```
-XX:MaxHeapSize=1024m
```

You can specify your own memory size.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have many parameter in eclipse.ini

This is the best configuration for Eclipse NEON and o.s. Windows 10 with 4GB of Ram:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
–launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
–launcher.defaultAction
openFile
–launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
–launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
–launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/javaw.exe
–launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

If you have 8GB of Ram modify **-XX:PermSize=512m** and **-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m**.
For complete example see [here](https://lentux-informatica.com/best-configuration-eclipse-ini/).