# When I run my Java program I have heap size issue

Tags: java, linux, centos, heap-memory

When I run my Java program in command line in linux (centos), it works, but it gives me heap size error when I run it by Eclipse IDE.

Why? and how can fix it?

Comment: Try increasing the max heap size in the VM arguments.

Comment: could give me some tips how to do it

Comment: In the Run Configuration, try adding `-Xmx512m` in the VM arguments section. You can access your run configuration from Run -> Run Configurations.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313393/how-to-increase-heap-size-in-eclipse (except adjust the memory to some reasonable value, like 512m)

Comment: You might also want to look at your code in the debugger and see what is using so much memory, Unless your making a lot of instances or you have a huge data structure.

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact error you're getting? This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap

Comment: I went to Run->Run Configurations -> VM arguments,     but i do know where and how to add this -Xmx512m, and by the way, what is this for?

Comment: I just copyed and pasted it in the box under VM arguments, and It worked :) thank indeed