# Where is this memory exception coming from?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl

I'm writing a 3D application in Java. I'm loading fields that contain around 65000 vertices each. These fields can translate, rotate etc. When a field scrolls out of the frustum it is culled, VBOs are cleared and the element arrays are stored in a memory buffer. I buffer a max of 5 of these fields. Any more than that they start going to file.

When I hit around 8 visible fields (520000) vertices the program crashes with system out of memory. I thought I was overloading the gpu memory but using GPU Shark I can see it only hits about 25%. My system has 8GB of RAM and looking via Task manager the memory usage barely registers. It sits at about 51%. So what am I running out of?

I use Concurrent Hashmaps to store my vertex data. I don't explicitly destroy/nullify them when not in use but that has never caused problems before.

I am using the OpenGL library via LWJGL.

Comment: i'm guessing the "out of memory" comes from jvm. what is your -Xmx setting? for xmx see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5374501/1737819

Comment: Is there a way for me to increase the alottment?

Comment: @eric_the_animal check the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using eclipse, try to increase the eclipse heap size and then again try it out. JVM do not allow your whole RAM to the heap.

[How to increase application heap size in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313393/how-to-increase-application-heap-size-in-eclipse)

Comment: Yes, I just finished doing that after seeing the comment from Willmore.  Works like a charm and now I can actually see what the issue is.  There are fields that are straggling (being rendered even though they should be culled).