# How to enable Java VisualVM to display numbers in human readable format?

Tags: java, visualvm, jvisualvm

Is there any setting that I could configure to enable jvisualvm to display memory and other numbers in human readable format, i.e. in MBs instead of in Bytes, etc.

I did investigate but couldn't find any.

Comment: Here your question is off-topic because of the rule: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Try it on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thanks for the feedback but I'm not sure or this is somewhat in the grey area. There are tons of appreciated questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313393/how-to-increase-application-heap-size-in-eclipse

Comment: Well I almost agree. Your question explicit says `Is there any plugin...` just following rules here. :) If you take that out it would be just a configuration question and there isn't nothing against it ;)

Comment: thanks, done. @JorgeCampos