# How to solve java heap space error in parsing xlsm file || i am giving maximum heap space in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi, heap-memory

I am trying to parse a xlsm file with apache POI and i am giving the maximum heap space allocation in the eclipse , but every time i am getting heap space exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur.createElementXobj(Cur.java:260)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.startElement(Cur.java:2997)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNode(Locale.java:1420)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNodeChildren(Locale.java:1403)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNode(Locale.java:1445)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNodeChildren(Locale.java:1403)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNode(Locale.java:1445)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNodeChildren(Locale.java:1403)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.loadNode(Locale.java:1445)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1385)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1370)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:370)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:144)
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorksheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:183)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:175)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.parseSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:438)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:403)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:190)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:296)
at com.excelmanager.ExcelManager.openWorkbook(ExcelManager.java:26)
at com.excelmanager.ExcelManager.<init>(ExcelManager.java:19)
at com.excelmanager.ActivityLauncher.main(ActivityLauncher.java:51)
```

I am giving the vm argument screen of eclipse
[image]

Please help

Comment: It would be great for us to help if you can update your question with minimal sample code.

Comment: @MilanSavaliya which article

Comment: Sorry, I did forgot to attach. Refer it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313393/how-to-increase-application-heap-size-in-eclipse

Comment: If solutions in above articles do not work for your case. I would recommend you to update your question with sample file which we can use, along with the code you are using to parse it.

Comment: it may happen that your program is even exceeding the memory arguments defined

Comment: @MilanSavaliya it is saying that Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1548288KB object heap

Comment: @MilanSavaliya i am updating the  question with the sample code and f ile