# pdfbox git merge example. Where the final merged file is stored?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to use the pdfbox library for java to merge thousands of small pdf files. Looking for an example I found one on the pdfbox site and specifically in the examples it has([PDFMergerExample](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PDFMergerExample.java?view=markup)).
But where the final merged file is saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a class, not a complete sample...
The entry method returns an InputStream, from there you can read the result and store ist to e.g. a file.

```
public InputStream merge(final List<RandomAccessRead> sources) throws IOException
```

https://www.baeldung.com/convert-input-stream-to-a-file

Comment: I overlooked that it had a return type. Thanks. But at the end it didn't work. With 500 files or more it throws "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".

Comment: -Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size

Comment: or try merging in slices of x files

Comment: I am using Eclipse. Where should i change the max of Java heap size?

Comment: How to increase application heap size in Eclipse? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313393/how-to-increase-application-heap-size-in-eclipse

Comment: Thanks a lot. I couldn't use more than 1750m but this was a 32bit JRE restriction. When I changed to 64bit was ok.