# How to Increase Java Heap Space in Worklight Server?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am getting JVM Heap space error in Worklight when tried to deploy Android Application.

```
Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server: InputStream error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

How to fix this issue.

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly a Worklight issue, but rather an Eclipse issue.

See possible solutions at:

- [How to increase Java Heap Size in Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse?)
- [How to increase application heap size in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313393/how-to-increase-heap-size-in-eclipse)
- [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596009/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space)
- [Increase JVM max heap size for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382932/increase-jvm-max-heap-size-eclipse)

Answer (score 9):

For me the error related to the Heap size of the server, not the heap size of eclipse.

On the server view, expand the Worklight server and select the jvm options, add (for example) -Xmx1024m

[image]

Comment: For me this also turned out to be the heap size of the server not of Eclipse.