# Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Never asked a worklight question, so I'm just going to post my server console log:

I open my project in worklight console and get the following:

```
Application Error
SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter:110'
javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:110)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
at [internal classes]
```

[2014-04-03 16:23:09]             Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server: Worklight module UIN was not successfully started. Full details of the error are available from the Worklight Development Server console.

```
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0/wlp-1.0.3.20130524-0951) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://[fd34:cdbe:6fe7:7d00:1610:9fff:fed4:3a73]:10080/UIN0rbcxmobile/
[ERROR   ] readExistingData failed
Java heap space
[WARNING ] Script processing failure
error in script file line: 119 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[ERROR   ] could not reopen database
error in script file line: 119 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0188E: Failed to connect to HSQL database : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (error in script file line: 119 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space) [project UIN0rbcxmobile]
[ERROR   ] FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /UIN0rbcxmobile [project UIN0rbcxmobile]
Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/eveo/Documents/workspace2/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'brokerSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerSessionFactory' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/eveo/Documents/workspace2/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rssBrokerDS' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rssBrokerDS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/eveo/Documents/workspace2/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklight-direct' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklight-direct' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/eveo/Documents/workspace2/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (error in script file line: 119 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space)
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/eveo/Documents/workspace2/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'brokerSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerSessionFactory' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/eveo/Documents/workspace2/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rssBrokerDS' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rssBrokerDS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/eveo/Documents/workspace2/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklight-direct' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklight-direct' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/eveo/Documents/workspace2/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (error in script file line: 119 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space)
    at com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator.contextInitialized(JeeProjectActivator.java:146)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2220)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by (repeated) ... : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/eveo/Documents/workspace2/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'brokerSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerSessionFactory' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/eveo/Documents/workspace2/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rssBrokerDS' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rssBrokerDS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/eveo/Documents/workspace2/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklight-direct' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklight-direct' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/eveo/Documents/workspace2/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (error in script file line: 119 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator.loadSpringConfiguration(JeeProjectActivator.java:273)
    at com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator.contextInitialized(JeeProjectActivator.java:134)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (error in script file line: 119 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource.getConnection(WorklightDataSource.java:234)
    at com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource.afterPropertiesSet(WorklightDataSource.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: error in script file line: 119 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: error in script file line: 119 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readExistingData(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderBase.readAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.processScript(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.openPersistence(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.decode(StringCoding.java:133)
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:173)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:443)
    at org.hsqldb.lib.LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readLoggedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readExistingData(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderBase.readAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.processScript(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.openPersistence(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource.getConnection(WorklightDataSource.java:234)
    at com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource.afterPropertiesSet(WorklightDataSource.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)

[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application UIN0rbcxmobile started in 7.607 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://[fd34:cdbe:6fe7:7d00:1610:9fff:fed4:3a73]:10080/_MobileBrowserSimulator/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application _MobileBrowserSimulator started in 0.037 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight is ready to run a smarter planet.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized
    ... 4 more

[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized
    ... 4 more

[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the errors in the log seem to stem from:

> error in script file line: 119 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap
>   space

So, try increasing the Java heap space of your application server...

If the above is from your Worklight Development Server, you can simply open the jvm options and increase it there.

Also see: [How to Increase Java Heap Space in Worklight Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459454/how-to-increase-java-heap-space-in-worklight-server/18460323#18460323)

Add `-Xmx1024m`
[image]

Comment: I honestly had 0 hope of this working, but it worked perfectly. Thank you.