# Worklight Skin deployment Issue

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, skin

I am using worklight skin for my recent project for iOS hybrid application. I created skins for iPad retina.

When i am deploying first time my project with skin folder that time i am not getting any error but after that i deploy my project again it is throwing an error.

*If i deploy project without skin folder at that time also it's working fine.

Request you to all please suggest some working approch.

**Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server: InputStream error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

Thanks,

Amitesh Namdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the solution provided in the following question for Java heap space: [How to Increase Java Heap Space in Worklight Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459454/how-to-increase-java-heap-space-in-worklight-server)

---

For me the error related to the Heap size of the server, not the heap size of eclipse.

On the server view, expand the Worklight server and select the jvm options, add (for example) -Xmx1024m

[image]

Comment: What did you add to the skins folder? How much does it weigh in MBs?

Comment: HI Idan Adar,

Thanks for the great suggestion for me that suggestion is working. I did not user clear build after putting "Xmx1024m".

Thanks 
Amitesh