# How to increase Java Heap Space for Eclipse ADT Bundle

Tags: java, android, eclipse, memory, heap-memory

Ok. So, I am having a constant issue while trying to run my application to either the emulator or export a signed apk for testing. No matter what I do, I constantly get this issue:
[image: Issues 1]

This is what the memory allocation looks like while it is trying to load:
[image: Issues 2]
I have followed Every single how to: and advice guide I can, including the following links:
1) [How can I increase the JVM memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294268/how-can-i-increase-the-jvm-memory)
2) [Increase JVM max heap size for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382932/increase-jvm-max-heap-size-eclipse)
3) [Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943712/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space)
4) http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

But no matter what I do, I cannot get it to work and I am pulling my hair out trying to make it work...

Here is a screenshot of my Eclipse.ini file below:
[image: Issues 3]

Also, I have uninstalled and reinstalled the Eclipse ADT thinking that might fix it.

If someone can help me figure out what I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate the help as I have spent the past 6 hours trying to fix this so I can continue debugging even more issues :/

-Silmarilos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may had changed eclipse.exe file name.Just change back

Comment: Ha! Believe it or not, this was exactly the issue. I had changed it to differentiate the icon from the different eclipse I use for standard Java. Never would have guessed this was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Your question remind me that it made me confused too!

Comment: the answer is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
-Xms4096m
-Xmx4096m
```

to

```
-Xmx1024m    //Half of your RAM
-Xms100m     // ~ Half of your RAM/10
```