# Heap space error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

This is my error log. I tried everything including increasing the heap size in eclipse.ini.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.android.dx.rop.code.RegisterSpecSet.<init>(RegisterSpecSet.java:49)
at com.android.dx.rop.code.RegisterSpecSet.mutableCopy(RegisterSpecSet.java:383)
at com.android.dx.ssa.LocalVariableInfo.mutableCopyOfStarts(LocalVariableInfo.java:168)
at com.android.dx.ssa.LocalVariableExtractor.processBlock(LocalVariableExtractor.java:103)
at com.android.dx.ssa.LocalVariableExtractor.doit(LocalVariableExtractor.java:89)
at com.android.dx.ssa.LocalVariableExtractor.extract(LocalVariableExtractor.java:55)
at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaConverter.convertToSsaMethod(SsaConverter.java:49)
at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:98)
at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:72)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:299)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:139)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:94)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:682)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:188)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:786)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:597)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:726)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increase JVM max heap size for Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382932/increase-jvm-max-heap-size-for-eclipse)

Comment: Obviously, you didn't try **everything** :-)

Comment: The eclipse.ini sets the memory for Eclipse. Look at the Run Configuration to set the memory for your program.