# Updating eclipse max heap size in eclipse.ini has no effect

Tags: eclipse

I have updated the contents of `eclipse.ini` to include `-Xmx4G` instead of  `-Xmx2G`, but re-starting eclipse I still see (hovering over the memory utilization bar copied below) that the maximum heap size is a little less than 2G. Do I need to take a different approach to increasing the heap size used by eclipse?

[image]

Hovering the bar, I see: `max: 1821M`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase JVM max heap size for Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382932/increase-jvm-max-heap-size-for-eclipse)

Comment: That question has arcane answers, also none of which are very clear.

Comment: Where are you looking to see what is being used?

Comment: Added in the question now. Let me trace back how the Unity desktop launches eclipse though, making sure it does not override the `.ini` file. Sorry about that.

Comment: Also show us the eclipse.ini

Answer (score 0):

It only takes setting or updating the value of -Xmx such as to `-Xmx4G`. But this can be done either in eclipse.ini or in the command used to activate eclipse. The command will override eclipse.ini in this regard, so in case updating eclipse.ini doesn't work, need to examine and modify the command used to launch. In some desktop environments this might require a good memory or some effort to [find the launch command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709528/recovering-the-command-used-by-a-launcher-icon?noredirect=1#comment1043557_709528). I now renamed the question to better reflect the scenario for future searches.

Answer (score 0):

Add following:

```
-vmargs
-Xmx4G
```

to the very end of your eclipse.ini

Usual error is to include VM arguments before -vmargs argument in eclipse.ini, or to omit -vmrags altogether.