# How many cliques in a simple graph?

Tags: java, graph-algorithm

I have graph G(V,E) with E=120 and G=5340. I want to enumerate and extract all maximal cliques by using the [Bron-Kerbosch clique detection algorithm](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=SerialFIM-master/org/jgrapht/alg/BronKerboschCliqueFinder.java), but when I run the program in Eclipse, it fails with this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.newNode(Unknown Source)
```

How can I determine how many cliques there are in a simple graph?

Comment: Well. Looks like you need more heap space.

Comment: thank you  Dave Newton but I wanted to know how many clicks in a simple graph...

Comment: And how I can resolve the heap space problem

Comment: Increase your heap size

Comment: please coud you  telle me how can I increase the heap size?

Comment: Look it up, if you can't figure it out after looking it up, then ask a question on what you're stuck on.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382932/increase-jvm-max-heap-size-for-eclipse/29024961#29024961

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested you need to increase your heap size
or try another alternative, for example: you can reduce clique problem to SAT problem, and solve it by using any MiniSAT online solver