# Get a Constant rps in Jmeter

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have been trying to use JMeter to test my server. I have a cloudsearch endpoint on AWS. I have to test if it can scale upto 25000 requests per second without failing. I have tried JMeter with a constant throughput timer with throughput = 1500000 per second and running 1000 threads. I ran it for 10 mins. But When I review the aggregate report it shows an average of only 25 requests per second. How do i get an average of around 25000 requests per second?

Comment: Did you checked **"Loop count forever"**?

Comment: what is the response time?

Comment: response time was around 2000 - 4000 ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Constant Throughput Timer** can only **pause** the threads to reach specified "Target Throughput" value so make sure you provide enough virtual users (threads) to generate desired **"requests per minute"** value.

You don't have enough **Threads** to achieve such Requests per second!!!

To get an average (~25000) requests per second, you have to **increase the Number of threads**.

**Remember**, The number of threads will impact results if your server faces slowdowns. If so and you don't have enough threads then you will not be injecting the expected load and end up with fewer transactions performed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to increase the number of concurrent users to be at least 25000 (it assumes 1 second response time, if you have 2 seconds response time - you will need 50000)
2. JMeter default configuration is not suitable for high loads, it is good for tests development and debugging, however when it comes to the real load you need to consider some constraints, i.e.:

   - Run JMeter test in [non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
   - [Increase JVM Heap Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452765/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-jvm) and [tune other parameters](http://crunchify.com/jvm-tuning-heapsize-stacksize-garbage-collection-fundamental/)
   - Disable all [listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) during the test

   If above tips don't help follow other recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/nine-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article or consider [Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)