# Hive: Read timeout exception

Tags: scala, hadoop, hive

The problem is when I'm trying to query smth from hive using my application e.g.
    `analyze table table_entity compute statistics` or for example `select count(*) from table_entity` sometimes I got such exception:`java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`

But when for example I query `show tables` or `show tblproperties table_entity` I didn't get such exception.

Has anyone faced with this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just try to increase JVM MAX Heap size of your cluster

Comment: you can go to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452765/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-jvm

Comment: @AnkurKumar I've tried to change it on my cloudera cluster in that way 
  `export CMF_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx3G -Xmx3G -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp"`  but this does not helped

Comment: @AnkurSingh I know it's been a while since this question was posted, but could you solve this problem? I'm facing this issue with a coworker and there's nothing on the web could help.

Comment: please checkout my answer, this will surely help!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is little late, but I was stuck with same sort of problem where we were not able to drop a table, we raised a case with Cloudera and following was the suggestion provided by them:

> Upon investigating the logs and the stack of messages we have observed
>   during the execution of the DROP query for the table "tableName",
>   the query got failed due to "Read time out" in HiveServer2 from
>   HiveMetastore. This means the drop operation of the table was not able
>   to get complete at Metadata level. (In general - DROP operation
>   deletes the metadata details of a table from HMS) We are suspecting
>   that the metadata of this table is not up to date and might have more
>   data which could have led to the timeout. Could you please perform the
>   below steps and let us know your feedback?
>
> 1. Login to Beeline-Hive.
> 2. Update the partition level metadata in Hive Metastore:
>          MSCK REPAIR TABLE db.table_name DROP PARTITIONS;
> 3. Compute the statistics for the table:
>          ANALYZE TABLE db.tableName partition(col1, col2) compute statistics noscan;
> 4. Drop the partitions of the table first using the query: 
>          ALTER TABLE db.tableName DROP [IF EXISTS] PARTITION partition_spec[, PARTITION partition_spec, ...]
>          Please replace the partition values in the above command accordingly as per the partitions of the table.
> 5. Increase the Hive Metastore client socket timeout.
>          set hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout=1500. 
>          This will give an increased socket time out only for this session. Hence run the next step #6 in the same session.
> 6. Drop the table tableName;
>          DROP TABLE db.tableName;

Although the question here is regarding Analyze table issue but this answer is intended to cover all the other issues related to Read Timeout Error.

I have shown my scenario(drop statement), however these steps will surely help across all sorts of queries which leads to the  Read timeout Exception.

Cheers!