# HeapSpace with springboot when download file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I using springboot 1.5.4.RELEASE with java 1.8 and I create a controller that allow download a file from a restController this is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validar/{hash}", produces =  MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody byte[] getArquivoFromHash(@PathVariable String hash) throws IOException {        
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(protocoloService.recuperarArquivoCertidaoAssinado(hash));

}
```

and my recuperarArquivoCertidaoAssinado returns a FileInputStream from a File

so when I try to download a large file (something like 50MB) I got the heapspace

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: How big is your JVMs heapsize ? Did you increase it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase Heap size of JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452765/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-jvm)

Comment: But does not Java 8 not automatically allocate? I just give you an idea of when I want it, if I increase it it will only take a little longer to give problem

Comment: No, there is a certain limit and you can increase this limit. Either you need a streaming approach or increase your heap to (number of concurrent connections * biggest file + base for application )