# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, jvm

I have tried various workarounds but still facing the same issue.
Below I have been using till now.

-Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -DENV=uat -DENV_INSTANCE=uata

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to `Help -> Edit custom VM options`
- Put/replace `-Xmx2g` in here to increase max heap size to 2 gigabytes for example.
- Close the file and restart IntelliJ.

See also [How to increase Heap size of JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452765/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-jvm)

Comment: Also check the JDK version you are using , I switched to jdk1.8.0_66 and the mentioned error was resolved.