# Kotlin: Exception handling in recursion

Tags: kotlin, recursion, exception

Here is my function:

```
fun quickSort(data: List<PhEntry>, maxTime: Long = 0L): List<PhEntry> {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > maxTime) throw Exception("")
    if (data.size < 2) return data
    val pivot = data[data.lastIndex / 2]
    val equal = data.filter { it.name == pivot.name }
    val greater = data.filter { it.name > pivot.name }
    val lesser = data.filter { it.name < pivot.name }
    return quickSort(lesser, maxTime) + equal + quickSort(greater, maxTime)
}
```

I call this from a time keeping function:

```
fun sortTimer(data: List<PhEntry>, time: Long = 0L, sortFunc: (sortedData: List<PhEntry>, time: Long) -> List<PhEntry>): Pair<List<PhEntry>?, Long> {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    return try{
        val result = sortFunc(data, startTime + time)
        Pair(result, System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Pair(null, System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)
    }
}
```

The data is a huge telephone directory containing a million entries. The program is supposed to try sorting the entire list within 90 seconds. If it is not possible, then it should go for a simple search of the non-sorted list.

Time values that are 90000L (90 seconds) or more causes the program to freeze. It does not throw any exception just freezes. I just tried using 1000L as the value for `time` and the program works fine.

Why is this happening? I want to basically terminate the recursion if time limit is reached. I can't use `kotlinx` libraries as I am doing a course from hyperskill and they don't allow me to modify the gradle file.

---

Edit 1:

On inserting a `println(System.currentTimeMillis())` in the `quickSort` function, the function freezes when `System.currentTimeMillis()` exceeds `maxTime`. And then nothing happens. The recursion is very deep at this point, is that the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried giving the process more heap memory?  (It's not a problem with the depth of recursion directly, as that would cause a StackOverflowError.  But each call is generating several lists, and the JVM can get very slow when the heap is about full.)

Comment: How to do this? Can you please give me a link which may explain about this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452765/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-jvm

Comment: The script does not throw `OutOfMemoryException` though. Will try this and get back.

Comment: seems an inefficient implementation of the quick sort... note that you iterate over your `data` already 3 times, just to get the 3 lists of equal, lesser and greater... you may want to replace your algorithm with just `data.sortedBy { it.name }`, which most probably already performs better... Also if you are on the JVM you may want to use an executor service where you specify a timeout when getting the value... that should be way easier than what you do now...