# Java Heap Error for StringBuilder while reading zips

Tags: java, stringbuilder, zipstream

I have a scenario to read zip files from a server URL. But I get a Java heap error when i append the string in the stringbuilder

```java
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
  
    String url = "https://server/test.zip";
    LOG.info("Url {}", url);
    String content = readZipFileFromRemote(url);
    System.out.println(content);
        
    }

  
    private static String readZipFileFromRemote(String remoteFileUrl) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
        URL url = new URL(remoteFileUrl);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 1024);

         ZipInputStream stream = new ZipInputStream(in);
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         ZipEntry entry;
         while ((entry = stream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
             int read;
             while ((read = stream.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
              sb.append(new String(buffer, 0, read));
            }
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return sb.toString();
    }
```

Error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
   at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase Heap size of JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452765/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-jvm)

Comment: Not sure, I am running this as a Kubernetes cron job. It works alright in tomcat in my local machine

Comment: Then in crontab, edit and add that flag.

Comment: If this is Kubernetes, what are the requests/limits configured for your container/pod and how much resources are available on your Node(s)?

Comment: MEMORY_REQUEST=600
CPU_REQUEST=100
MEMORY_LIMIT=1500
CPU_LIMIT=500

Comment: Why can't you output the string incrementally instead of first building the full string and then printing it?

Comment: how do i do that @MarkRotteveel

Comment: I have solved the issue by directly printing the lines instead of string Builder. 
                                                                                                            
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                    String nextLine;
                    while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        LOG.debug("{}",nextLine);
                    }